# AMDGPU doesn't work with hashcat

Tags: linux-kernel, gentoo, hybrid-graphics, opencl

AMDGPU doesn't work with hashcat, anyone knows how to fix this problem?

```
$ ~ hashcat -I
hashcat (v6.2.6) starting in backend information mode

clCreateCommandQueue(): CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

OpenCL Info:
============

OpenCL Platform ID #1
  Vendor..: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Name....: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Version.: OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP.dbg (3513.0)

OpenCL Platform ID #2
  Vendor..: Intel(R) Corporation
  Name....: Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
  Version.: OpenCL 2.1 LINUX

  Backend Device ID #1
    Type...........: CPU
    Vendor.ID......: 8
    Vendor.........: Intel(R) Corporation
    Name...........: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Version........: OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
    Processor(s)...: 8
    Clock..........: 1600
    Memory.Total...: 11809 MB (limited to 1476 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 5872 MB
    Local.Memory...: 32 KB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 2.0 
    Driver.Version.: 18.1.0.0920

OpenCL Platform ID #3
  Vendor..: Intel(R) Corporation
  Name....: Intel(R) OpenCL Graphics
  Version.: OpenCL 3.0 

  Backend Device ID #2
    Type...........: GPU
    Vendor.ID......: 8
    Vendor.........: Intel(R) Corporation
    Name...........: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
    Version........: OpenCL 3.0 NEO 
    Processor(s)...: 24
    Clock..........: 1100
    Memory.Total...: 9447 MB (limited to 2047 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 4672 MB
    Local.Memory...: 64 KB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Driver.Version.: 23.22.026516

OpenCL Platform ID #4
  Vendor..: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Name....: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Version.: OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3180.7)

  Backend Device ID #3
    Type...........: GPU
    Vendor.ID......: 1
    Vendor.........: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
    Name...........: AMD Radeon Graphics
    Version........: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (3180.7)
    Processor(s)...: 5
    Clock..........: 600
    Memory.Total...: 2047 MB (limited to 1522 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 0 MB
    Local.Memory...: 32 KB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Driver.Version.: 3180.7
    PCI.Addr.BDF...: 01:00.0
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `clinfo` (mainly the end of it which shows which platform gets picked by default). Chances are that hashcat is picking the Intel GPU instead of the AMD one.

Comment: intelgpu is working properly but amdgpu doesn't work, in the other hand clinfo output is too long I couldn't post it fully over here

Comment: ```https://easyupload.io/ik406b```

Comment: Do You have a [Crossfire Graphics Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFire).  The reason the intel graphics is chosen is because it's the card that's rendering what's being displayed (it's active)